# Can you construct after instantiation? Avoiding empty constructor

Tags: c++, class, oop, instantiation

I have a class which has a member attribute consisting of an object defined elsewhere. In the code below, `A` contains a public attribute `var` which is a `B`:

```
class B {
    public:
    int x, y;
    std::vector<int> z;
        B(int a, int b, std::vector<int> c) {
            x = a; y = b; z = c;
        }
};

class A {
    public:
        B var;
        A(int i, int j) {
            std::vector<int> someVector;
            B(i, j, someVector);
        }
};

int main() {
    A foo(5, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

This (obviously) doesn't compile as `var` is instantiated upon an instantiation of `A`, too late for it to be constructed.

The best way I can do something similar is modify some code:

```
class B {
    public:
    int x, y;
    std::vector<int> z;
        B() {}
        void setAttributes(int a, int b, std::vector<int> c) {
            x = a; y = b; z = c;
        }
};

class A {
    public:
        B var;
        A(int i, int j) {
            std::vector<int> someVector;
            B.setAttributes(i, j, someVector);
        }
};
```

This does compile because attributes are set after instantiation.

But is there a way to remain closer to the first code snippet?

Comment: You are probably looking for a [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A(int i, int j) : var(i, j, {}) {}
```

Also, in your code `B(i, j, someVector);` does **not** initialize member variable `var`, and `B.setAttributes(i, j, someVector);` wouldn't compile at all.

Answer (score 1):

if you cannot define a useful default constructor and don't want the ugly two step initialization, I guess there is no way around a pointer to B. Something like

```
#include <memory>

class B {
    public:
        int x, y;
        std::vector<int> z;

        B(int a, int b, std::vector<int> c) {
            x = a; y = b; z = c;
        }
};

class A {
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<B> var;
        A() {
            std::vector<int> someVector;
            var = std::make_unique<B>(5, 2, someVector);
        }
};

int main() {
    A foo();
    return 0;
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: In OP's code all the necessary data to construct `var` is provided to the constructor of `A`, so the initialization can happen in the member initializer list as shown in the other answer, without pointers, two-step initialization or default-constructor.

Comment: You're absolutely right anout the member initialization. I assumed, that this was just a very minimal example and in a real world code something would be put into someVector in A's constructor, before passing it to B. Regarding the type alias... well... I'll remove it.

Comment: Even if the constructor puts stuff in the vector first, that can still be done in a function/lambda call in the initializer list.

Comment: True, didn't think about it that way. Thanks for the feedback.